# Backgroundworker : exception during cancellation

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, backgroundworker

I have a background worker which can be cancelled.

The normal flows interrupt itself when the CancelPending variable turns to true (responding to user interaction on UI which call worker.CancelAsynch() ), exceptions are thrown because if that (since normal flow is interrupted, lots of null ref exception are thrown)

So when the worker returns, I want to be able to distinguish exception that have been thrown when the worker
was canceled (to silently ignore them) from exceptions thrown when worker was not canceled (to report them to UI).

My code is as follow (sorry for the c#/vb mix ...) :

The worker class:

```
Public Class ClassBaseGetObjectsWorker
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    

 Protected Overrides Sub OnDoWork(ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
        Try

            Dim cpt As Int16 = 0
            While cpt < 5
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                cpt = cpt + 1
                If CheckForCancellation() Then
                    'Simulating exception due to cancel
                    Throw New Exception("Exception du to cancel !")
                End If
            End While

        Catch exc As Exception
            e.Cancel = Me.CancellationPending
            Throw exc
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

The call back:

```
void setObjSetCollWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Cancelled) {
        resultLabel.Text += "Canceled";
        //e.Error is selently ignored
    }
    else {
        if (e.Error != null) {
            //Reporting errors arising during normal (uncanceled) flow
            throw e.Error.InnerException;
        }
        else {
            //Worker process finished without error or being canceled.
            updateUIAfterBackgroundJob();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when I'm doing worker.CancelAsynch(), e.Cancelled is set to false (which is not what I expected) in the Completed call back. If I comment out "Trow exc" in the worker, if I test again, e.Cancelled is correctly set to true.

What is the cleanest way to get the information I want, that is: I want to know if the exception popping out in the completed handler was thrown when the worker was in the cancellationPending state or not?

Comment: What does the worked code look like, and how does it handle being canceled?

Comment: The worker is similar to the simulation code above : it goes through several level of function call, each doing loops wich are exiting if CancellationPending (checked through a delegate) turned to true.

Those loops and functions prematured exits lead to exceptions that are "normal" considering the facts that the flow is interrupted and the result will be discarded. 

Why do you ask this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the best way to structure the code in your OnDoWork()-implementation is to throw an exception when you detect cancellation, do the following:

Create a CancelException:

```
public class CancelException: Exception {}
```

Throw this CancelException when you detect that cancellation is pending:

```
if(CheckForCancellation()) throw new CancelException();
```

Add a try-catch around the code in your OnDoWork()-method:

```
protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e){
  try{
    //...
  }
  catch(CancelException){
    // silently return
    return;
  }
}
```

That way your code will obey the BackgroundWorker-contract (which is to return from OnDoWork() when you detect cancellation pending, rather than to throw an exception), and the Cancelled property should now be as you expect

Comment: A not so nice alternative would be adding a public member "WasCancelled" on my BackgroundWorker derived class that can be set to true in the OnDoWork catch block (Me.WasCancelled = Me.CancellationPending). This member could be then used in the completed call back.